# c++-cli how to replace "\" with "\\"

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying replace all symbols in a string with "\" to "\\". But it doesn't replace, and I don't know why. It works fine when trying replace "a" to "b". Code below:

```
 Private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

 OpenFileDialog ^ofd = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
 if (ofd->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
 {
     StreamReader ^read = gcnew StreamReader(File::OpenRead(ofd->FileName));
     textBox3->Text = ofd->FileName->Replace("\"", "\\");
 }
```

Comment: You are now trying to replace a double quote with a single backslash.  A filename will never contain a double quote.  Not that clear what is meant, especially since it seem to make so little sense to set the Text property to such a string, consider `Replace("\\", "\\\\")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: `Replace("\\", "\\\\")`.

`\` is the escaping character, `\\` produces a literal backslash.

(I assume you want to replace all `\` with `\\`, like replacing `a` with `b`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think a typo in your code.

Do you mean change the single '\' character to two '\' characters ??

Try Replace("\", "\\");

You need use '\' to signify a single '\' character - so need 4 of them to specify 2 '\' characters.